# grails: how to dynamically construct a form?

Tags: forms, grails

I need to create a dynamic form in grails which has various dynamically created input boxes at runtime, which then submits its params to a controller just like a form created at compile time.  Any ideas?

The view gsp might look like this:

```
<g:form controller="report" action="view">          
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <!-- insert some inuput params here at runtime -->
</g:form>
```

and the action controller would be:

```
class ReportController {
def view = {
    def someDynamicParam = "someParam"
    if (params["someParam"] != null) {
       ...
    }
```

The problem is I have no idea how to render the form input fields in a way that grails will understand them on submission.

Comment: Run `grails install-templates` and have a look at the script which is used to generate scaffolding views. There may be a hint or two in there.

Comment: where do you want the input fields created - at the client browser or at the server side? accordingly look at zoran119's comment or Sérgio   's answer respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like

```
<g:form controller="report" action="view">          
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <g:if test="${checkIfParamsExists}">
    <input type="text" id="newParamName"/>
  </g:if>
</g:form>
```

And in the controller side, your code should work fine.

Comment: I get the idea, many thanks.  As a secondary issue, I presume I would also need to add javascript to do any client side validation, e.g. to check they didnt type chars into a number type input.  If I did this check on the server side, its too late, as I wont be able to show which part of the input form had the error as it was alread submitted and I would end up on a new page.

Comment: While generating forms grails also generates all client side validations required according to the domain used. So, after generating the form just copy the part of params you want and paste it inside the g:if part. The part of form looks like this (you need to copy this part for each params)
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: personInstance, field: 'age', 'error')} required">
 <label for="age">
  <g:message code="person.age.label" default="Age" />
  <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
 </label>
 <g:field name="age" type="number" value="${personInstance.age}" required=""/>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

To create dynamic input's you need JavaScript. I suggest you to use some framework to make it easier. Taking JQuery as example:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'foo'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Then you need to think how to bind it to a Domain Class. Looking at your question I cannot see what you need, but let's make an example where the user can set values:

```
//domain class
class MyDomainClass {
  String value
}

//javascript to add a new value
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'values'
}).appendTo('form');

//controller submit action
class MyController {
  def save() {
    def values = params.list('values') //get the list of values
    values.each {
      MyDomain instance = new MyDomain(value: it)
      instance.save()
    }
  }
}
```

The key here is to use the same `name` in your html, and to use `params.list()` to transform the submited values in a List.

Comment: You don't *need* javascript.  That's just one way to do it.  He could write a tag library to help.  Or just have some iteration and conditional logic on the GSP.  JavaScript would probably be my last resort for dynamic forms.

Comment: Right, I think that the OP wanted something like a button "add more" that create new input's. If it's just to check if some input need to appear or not I agree with you.